# Laucher for external PHP objects

Tags: php, automation

I would like to do something like:

library.php:

```
require_once "laucher.php";

    class Test{
        public function __construct(){
            print "test";
        }
    }

    class Foo extends Bar{
        public function __construct(){
            $t = new Test();
        }
    }

    class Bar{
        public function __construct(){

        }
    }
```

And in laucher.php, I would like to create a Foo object as $t = new Foo();

How Can I create Foo Objects in laucher.php? I would like to create an "auto-laucher" of Foo();

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php. You wouldn't be able to create a `Foo` object in the launcher.php, because at the time PHP is requiring/parsing the file, Foo has not been defined yet.

Comment: How could I auto-execute Foo from an external file ?

Comment: Include(require_once) it's definition. (btw: you don't "execute" a class)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the file `Foo` is located in. So...

```
include("foo_file.php");
```

Then you can instantiate Foo.

```
$my_object = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create Foo objects before Foo has been defined. Therefore you can't create Foo objects inside "laucher.php" if you include it before the class declarations.

However, if laucher.php is included *after* the class declarations you should be able to create Foo objects inside. So I think this would work:

```
class Test{
    public function __construct(){
        print "test";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar{
    public function __construct(){
        $t = new Test();
    }
}

class Bar{
    public function __construct(){

    }
}

require_once "laucher.php";
```

Comment: Auto load worked fine! Thank you! The require_once at the end whould works, but I don't like the idea to manage it at the end! Thank guys!